# Using try and catch String input

Tags: java

What I'm doing is asking the user to input a month. I've put in a `if` and `else if` to say whether the **month > 12 or month < 1** and re-ask the user to input a month. Im trying to use the try and catch statement to catch the user entering a string and tell them to enter a month. The problem with my code is that when it catches the user entering a string it command line **keeps repeating** the "Please enter a month 1-12" and let user re enter the month . Can anyone stop the problem i'm having trouble with.

I've tried insert the `month.scan.nextInt()` into the `catch` but I get an error im really confused.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Price {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        userInput();
    }

    public static void userInput() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int month, day, year;
        boolean i = true;
        System.out.println("Please enter a month MM: ");
```

Comment: Just some notes on style: 1) Instead of `while(i == true)`, just put `while(i)` since i is already a boolean. 2) Variable names `i`, `j` and `k` should only be used for integer for loop index variables, array/matrix indexes and so on. Name descriptively otherwise. 3) Pairs of braces should be indented to the same width into the document, not indented as-much-as-you-feel-like, and your level of indentation inwards and outwards should be consistent. 4) Similarly, be consistent on whether the opening { brace is on a new line or on the same line as the previous statement. Pick one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because your code does not consume invalid input in the `catch` clause. Your program tries to read it again and again, causing another exception.

Changing your code as follows should fix the problem:

```
catch(InputMismatchException imme) { 
    System.out.println("Please enter a month 1-12");
    scan.next(); // Ignore the invalid input
}
```

If you would like to make your code more readable to others, come up with names that explain their purpose. For example, variable `i` is used to decide if the reading should continue or not. Renaming it to `continueReading` would make your loop easier to understand:

```
while (continueReading) ... // You do not need "== true" after a boolean variable
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user enters a month out of the specified range (e.g., `23`), watch what happens:

1. The `if`-statement evaluates to `false` and goes to the `else` block.
2. A message is printed, and then the user enters text again.
3. The loop begins again, and the user enters text for a second time.

Thus, you are having text that isn't being checked. Try removing the line

```
month = scan.nextInt();
```

after the call to print the error message.

Comment: Very helpful thank you very much ive been watch youtube videos on try and catch for hours but you've been more helpful :)